# jquery selector not working in the elements i creating dynamically on some events

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

i am just practising in some king of exercise and stuck in a point i dont understand.in my code i got a button and when the user press it ,it creates 25 cells and place random numbers on them.After i tried to do some kind of things when the user clicks in each cell.Well it didnt work.the `$("td")` selector doesnt trigger at all.any help?

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("body").append("<p></p>")
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        $("#t1").append("<tr></tr>");
    }
    for (i=0; i<5; i++){
        $("#t1 tr").append("<td></td>");
    }
    for (i=0; i<25; i++){
        var z = Math.round((Math.random()*89)+10);
        $("#t1 tr td").eq(i).text(z);
    }
});

$("td").click(function(){
    //code goes here
});
```

Comment: What HTML are you working with? Are there any errors? @dotnetom: I'm not sure about that dupe, I may be tired and missing something, but it seems that the `<td>` elements are being created after the `<button>` is clicked, and the click-binding seems to happen *after* the `<td>` elements have been created?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the regular `.click()` method, you should use `.on()` on an element that already exists, but that will contain the `td` later, for example `$(document)` or the table your cells will appear in.

```
$(document).on('click', 'td', function() {
    //code here
});
```

[jQuery .on() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: If the `td` is being created after this code executes then this suffers the exact same problem for the exact same reason.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that. Updated my answer

Comment: still not working @David is right.

Comment: Works after the edit.Thanks